# Nuxt plus express caching solution

Tags: express, caching, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I have an application that has been created by Nuxt + Express using the kit below:

> https://nuxtjs.org/guide/installation

When I check it by https://gtmetrix.com, it shows me that my website does not supporting "**Leverage Browser Caching**" and listed some URLs such as:

```
site.com/_nuxt/pages/app.js
site.com/_nuxt/pages/abooutus.js
site.com/_nuxt/pages/contactus.js
site.com/_nuxt/pages/404.js

site.com/_nuxt/images/logo.png
site.com/_nuxt/images/slider1.png
```

My images and extra CSS files are located in folder **static**. How can I add this caching layer in this SSR website?